# How do I find a specific file in multiple drives? Batch

Tags: batch-file, directory

So I'm making an installer which installs in a specific file that would be located in one of multiple drives, and the file could be in any drive (C:\, E:\, D:\, etc.). So for example: I want to install ZK47 in E:\KNX\44C, but I want the system to automatically find the file KNX without going to E:\ and without user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look in all harddisks (Mediatype=12) if the folder exists:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where mediatype^=12 get caption /value') do if exist %%i:\KNX\44C echo found on drive: %%i:
```

`for /f %%i in ('command') do ...` is a common way to process the output of a command.

`wmic logicaldisk get caption` lists all existing drive letters.

`where mediatype=12` tells it to list only harddisks (inside the `for` construct you have to escape the `=` with a caret `^`).

`/value` defines the output format.

"normally" you would use `"tokens=2 delims=="` to get the string after `=` (`C:`). By using `:` as additional delimiter I avoid dealing with the ugly line endings of wmic.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add what did you tried as code,because it works for me

Comment: is `E:` a harddisk? a flash drive would have another mediatype. You can check with `wmic logicaldisk get caption,mediatype`

Comment: well... is it listed with `wmic logicaldisk get caption,mediatype` ?

Comment: so it should work. It works for me and it works for Hackoo. Can you post your exact code please?